# beamer presentation slide

Tags: beamer, itemize, presentations, slideshow

I have  this slide for a presentation:

```
\begin{frame}
{Bonjour}
 Hi
 \begin{itemize}
 \item blabla
 \begin{itemize}
 \item A
 \item B
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
 \begin{overlayarea}{1\textwidth}{0.6\textheight}
\only<1>{
\begin{block}
{La solution1} 
blablablablablablablablablabla
\end{block}
 }
\only<2>{
 \begin{block}
 {La solution2} 
  blablablablablablablablablabla
  \end{block}

      }
  \end{overlayarea} 
  \end{frame}
```

I want the subitem A and B to disappear when La solution1 and La solution2  appear and at the same time they should take the places of A and B. The Hi should stay though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? But I must admit, I am not sure which elements you want on which slides.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Bonjour}
 Hi
  \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item blabla



     \begin{onlyenv}<1>
             \begin{itemize}
             \item A
             \item B
            \end{itemize}
     \end{onlyenv}

    \begin{block}<2->
    {La solution1} 
        blablablablablablablablablabla
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}<2->
     {La solution2} 
      blablablablablablablablablabla
    \end{block}  



\end{itemize}
 \end{overlayarea}


  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]