# overlay items inside block?

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays

Refer to the first answer here [Display the definition of each items in beamer one by one using onslide or any method](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116913/display-the-definition-of-each-items-in-beamer-one-by-one-using-onslide-or-any-m) , i want to do a block with items inside that keep position after overlay ?

** Edited

I managed to do what I wanted naively because i don't know how it works with [<+->]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Présentation de MedsoftWorks Consulting}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1->Ingénierie applicative 
        \item<5-> Développement web
        \item<9> Digital et application mobile
    \end{itemize}
        \only<2-4> {\begin{block}{Les offres}
           \begin{itemize}
            \item<2-4> La formalisation des besoins.
            \item<3-4> La conception de cahier de charge.
            \item<4>  La réalisation du progiciel adapté à la 
          \end{itemize}
                \end{block}
               } 
        \only<6-8> {\begin{block}{Les offres}
          \begin{itemize}
            \item<6-8> La gestion des moyens de paiement.
            \item<7-8> La gestion de paiement sécurisé.
            \item<8> Le Webmastering et maintenance.
        \end{itemize}
            \end{block} 
             }
    \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please explain in more detail what you are asking? Are you concerned by the fact that the block gets shifted around? If so, you could use e.g. `overlayarea`. And it would certainly help if you post a document that shows the issue.

Comment: ok i edited the post

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339469/beamer-presentation-slide/339472#339472

Comment: @the-goat Does the linked answer solve your problem?

Comment: yes with some modifications, but with the code above work perfectly